# How do I get SysInternals DebugView to display indents?

Tags: .net, sysinternals, debugview

I'm using SysInternals DebugView with my .Net application.  I've tried using the Indent feature of the .Net Debug class, but DebugView just seems to represent this as a NewLine character.

Does anyone know if it's possible to get DebugView to display the indents?

**Sample Code:**

```
static void Main (string[] args)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Indent level: {0}", Debug.IndentLevel);

    Debug.Indent();
    Debug.WriteLine("Indent level: {0}", Debug.IndentLevel);
    Debug.Indent();
    Debug.WriteLine("Indent level: {0}", Debug.IndentLevel);
    Debug.Indent();
    Debug.WriteLine("Indent level: {0}", Debug.IndentLevel);

    Debug.Unindent();
    Debug.WriteLine("Indent level: {0}", Debug.IndentLevel);
    Debug.Unindent();
    Debug.WriteLine("Indent level: {0}", Debug.IndentLevel);
    Debug.Unindent();
    Debug.WriteLine("Indent level: {0}", Debug.IndentLevel);
}
```

**Output:**

```
[9632] Indent level: 0
[9632]
[9632] Indent level: 1
[9632]
[9632]
[9632] Indent level: 2
[9632]
[9632]
[9632]
[9632] Indent level: 3
[9632]
[9632]
[9632] Indent level: 2
[9632]
[9632] Indent level: 1
[9632] Indent level: 0
```

**What I'd Like to see:**

```
[9632] Indent level: 0
[9632]   Indent level: 1
[9632]     Indent level: 2
[9632]       Indent level: 3
[9632]     Indent level: 2
[9632]   Indent level: 1
[9632] Indent level: 0
```

Rik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But wait!  It looks like it is possible.  You just need to **turn off** the **Force Carriage Returns** feature on the **Options** menu.

I discovered the answer here:
http://forum.sysinternals.com/topic26797_post131196.html#131196

Here's the text:

> By default, the Force Carriage Returns option is enabled, which displays every string passed
>   to a debug output function on a separate line, whether or not that text is terminated with a
>   carriage return. If you disable that option in the Options menu, DebugView buffers output
>   text in memory and adds it to the display only when a carriage return is encountered or the
>   memory buffer is filled (approximately 4192 characters). This allows applications and drivers
>   to build output lines with multiple invocations of debug output functions.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can make DebugView do this way. It captures individual output writes, so it seems that when you do `Debug.WriteLine` Debug class outputs indentation space individually as separate `OutputDebugString` calls. What you definitely still can do is adding indentation space yourself and have your writes mapped into single underlying API calls:

```
string currentIndent = "  ";
// ...
Debug.WriteLine(currentIndent + "Indent level: {0}", Debug.IndentLevel);
```

Comment: I see.  So the DebugViewer outputs each call to OutputDebugString to a new line.  That makes sense now.
I think I'll probably have to implement some variation on your idea here where I manage the indent.

Answer (score 0):

```
Debug.IndentLevel = 0; Debug.WriteLine("Indent level: {0}", Debug.IndentLevel);
Debug.IndentLevel = 1; Debug.WriteLine("Indent level: {0}", Debug.IndentLevel);
Debug.IndentLevel = 2; Debug.WriteLine("Indent level: {0}", Debug.IndentLevel);
Debug.IndentLevel = 3; Debug.WriteLine("Indent level: {0}", Debug.IndentLevel);
Debug.IndentLevel = 3; Debug.WriteLine("Indent level: {0}", Debug.IndentLevel);
Debug.IndentLevel = 2; Debug.WriteLine("Indent level: {0}", Debug.IndentLevel);
Debug.IndentLevel = 1; Debug.WriteLine("Indent level: {0}", Debug.IndentLevel);
Debug.IndentLevel = 0; Debug.WriteLine("Indent level: {0}", Debug.IndentLevel);


Indent level: 0
    Indent level: 1
        Indent level: 2
            Indent level: 3
            Indent level: 3
        Indent level: 2
    Indent level: 1
Indent level: 0
```